# SUM CASE , sum all value in when instead of just 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

```
 $scoreboard->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN tgl IN ($dateFormat) THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS '$day'");
```

In this code column `tgl` will check if there is the same value in `$dateFormat` and if so it will then sum table `score`. `$dateFormat` is like this `'2022-12-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-02-01'`, the problem with this is an OR so they just check if the same value in `tgl` exist in those 3 value and if it find it in one of them it will just end.

Is there a way to reformat the query where it would sum the score of those 3 date ?

And could i have the same `AS $day` Name ? like `AS Day1` in two queries would the 2nd query add the data to the 1st one ?

Example :

| Name | tgl | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-12-01 | 100 |
| A | 2022-12-01 | 200 |
| A | 2022-12-01 | 300 |
| A | 2022-12-02 | 400 |
| A | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| A | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| A | 2022-01-03 | 200 |
| A | 2022-02-01 | 100 |
| A | 2022-02-01 | 200 |
| A | 2022-02-02 | 300 |

Output :

| Name | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 600 (sum of 2022-12-01) | 400 (sum of 2022-12-02) | 0 (cause theres no value in this date) |
| A | 100 (sum of 2022-01-01) | 0 (cause theres no value in this date) | 200 (sum of 2022-01-03) |
| A | 300 (sum of 2022-02-01) | 300 (sum of 2022-02-02) | 0 (cause theres no value in this date) |

Something like this what iam looking for

sorry bad english

Comment: have you tried to use [aggregates query](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#aggregates) ?

Comment: I look into that but idk how to implement that to here cause the query too specific in this case

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GROUP BY` instead of `CASE WHEN`.

Final SQL will be like `SELECT tgl, name, SUM(score) FROM tableName GROUP BY tgl, name;`.

Without testing, try this:

```php
DB::table("tableName")->select("tgl", "name")->selectRaw("SUM(score)")->groupBy("tgl", "name")->get();
```

Comment: i got null on that

Comment: i think its because i pass this data later using that alias `AS $day`

Comment: Okay i can get it to work but instead of becoming new column like i want instead it just goes to row

Comment: I don't know what you extrul want, because this answered is based on your question output table expect.

Comment: ah okay forgot,that the table only have those iam looking basically `Day 1` is all first month and there will be `Day 2` and so on, so your code is work  if that the table but i need to "skip" date , so sorry my example is bad i will edit

Comment: I can't get it, what do you mean "skip" date, because this query should be grouped correct if date different, are you trying to select specific date that in a date list?

Comment: If you are meaning conditions, just try add `->whereIn('tgl', $dateFormat)`.

Comment: Basically i got date range so date i dont need i dont wanna show